# Search function does not reset with input value of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have a search and highlight function which adds an inline style to the input value string on a content div.

The problem is that when the input is empty the inline style persists on the content.

How could I prevent this or write a workaround? Thank you in advance.

```js
/**
 * highlight 1.0.0
 * Licensed under MIT
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2016 yjteam
 * http://yjteam.co.kr
 *
 * GitHub Repositories
 * https://github.com/yjseo29/highlight.js
 */

if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
  throw new Error("JavaScript requires jQuery");
}

+(function($) {
  "use strict";
  var version = $.fn.jquery.split(" ")[0].split(".");
  if (
    (version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) ||
    (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1)
  ) {
    throw new Error("JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher");
  }
})(jQuery);

+(function($) {
  $.fn.highlight = function(word, options) {
    var option = $.extend(
      {
        background: "#ffff00",
        color: "#000",
        bold: false,
        class: "",
        ignoreCase: true,
        wholeWord: true
      },
      options
    );
    var findCnt = 0;

    if (this.length == 0) {
      throw new Error("Node was not found");
    }

    var $el = $('<span style="color:' + option.color + ';"></span>');
    if (option.bold) {
      $el.css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
    if (option.background != "") {
      $el.css("background", option.background);
    }
    if (option.class != "") {
      $el.addClass(option.class);
    }

    if (option.wholeWord) {
      word = "\\b" + escapeRegExp(word) + "\\b";
    }
    var re = new RegExp(word, option.ignoreCase == true ? "gi" : "g");

    this.each(function() {
      var content = $(this).html();

      $(this).html(
        content.replace(re, function(t) {
          findCnt++;
          $el.text(t);
          return $el.get(0).outerHTML;
        })
      );
    });
    return findCnt;

    function escapeRegExp(string) {
      return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
  };
})(jQuery);



// highlight search terms in content
var searchCnt = 0;

var option = {
  color: "black",
  background: "lightskyblue",
  bold: false,
  ignoreCase: true,
  wholeWord: true
};

$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
  var searchVal = $(this).val();
  // console.log("value", searchVal);
  if (!searchVal || searchVal === "") {
    console.log("no value", searchVal);
    if (searchVal === "") return;
  } else {
    console.log("value", searchVal);
    $(".searchtext").each(function() {
      $(this).highlight(searchVal, option);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchInput" class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search"><i type="reset" class="fas fa-search"></i></input>
<p class="searchtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: You'll have to remove all the `<span>` elements that you've added, at each run.

Comment: Thank you @Titus . This worked.

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Comment: Code works fine until you throw in HTML into the mix. Than it is not a simple reg exp with find/replace.

Answer (score 0):

With the advice of @Titus my workaround was to add a removeAttr call on the span tags within the content:

```
// highlight search terms in content
$("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
  var option = {
    color: "black",
    background: "lightskyblue",
    bold: false,
    ignoreCase: true,
    wholeWord: true
  };
  var searchVal = $(this).val();
  // console.log("value", searchVal);
  if (!searchVal || searchVal === "") {
    console.log("no value", searchVal);
        $(".searchtext")
         .find("span")
         .contents()
         .unwrap();
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("value", searchVal);
    $(".searchtext").each(function() {
      $(this).highlight(searchVal, option);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove all the spans that you've added at each run.

Something like this:

```js
/**
 * highlight 1.0.0
 * Licensed under MIT
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2016 yjteam
 * http://yjteam.co.kr
 *
 * GitHub Repositories
 * https://github.com/yjseo29/highlight.js
 */

if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
  throw new Error("JavaScript requires jQuery");
}

+(function($) {
  "use strict";
  var version = $.fn.jquery.split(" ")[0].split(".");
  if (
    (version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) ||
    (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1)
  ) {
    throw new Error("JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher");
  }
})(jQuery);

+(function($) {
  $.fn.highlight = function(word, options) {
    $(".highlightLibSpan").replaceWith(function(){
       return $(this).text();
    })
    
    var option = $.extend(
      {
        background: "#ffff00",
        color: "#000",
        bold: false,
        class: "",
        ignoreCase: true,
        wholeWord: true
      },
      options
    );
    var findCnt = 0;

    if (this.length == 0) {
      throw new Error("Node was not found");
    }

    var $el = $('<span class="highlightLibSpan" style="color:' + option.color + ';"></span>');
    if (option.bold) {
      $el.css("font-weight", "bold");
    }
    if (option.background != "") {
      $el.css("background", option.background);
    }
    if (option.class != "") {
      $el.addClass(option.class);
    }

    if (option.wholeWord) {
      word = "\\b" + escapeRegExp(word) + "\\b";
    }
    var re = new RegExp(word, option.ignoreCase == true ? "gi" : "g");

    this.each(function() {
      var content = $(this).html();

      $(this).html(
        content.replace(re, function(t) {
          findCnt++;
          $el.text(t);
          return $el.get(0).outerHTML;
        })
      );
    });
    return findCnt;

    function escapeRegExp(string) {
      return string.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|\[\]\/\\])/g, "\\$1");
    }
  };
})(jQuery);



// highlight search terms in content
var searchCnt = 0;

var option = {
  color: "black",
  background: "lightskyblue",
  bold: false,
  ignoreCase: true,
  wholeWord: true
};

$("#searchInput").on("input", function() {
  var searchVal = $(this).val();
  $(".searchtext").each(function() {
    $(this).highlight(searchVal, option);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchInput" class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="Search"><i type="reset" class="fas fa-search"></i></input>
<p class="searchtext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

The changes that I've made, was to add

```
$(".highlightLibSpan").replaceWith(function(){
   return $(this).text();
})
```

at the start of the library's function and to add the `highlightLibSpan` class to all the `<span>` elements that the library creates.

Also, instead of using the `keyup` event, you should probably use the `input` event to account for other events like **paste**